# Random number selection from array vs rounding off selected random number

Tags: random-variable, random-generation

Here is the thought experiment .

Objective : I need to select a random number in the search space between (1.00 and 4:00)

Case Scenarios

1. Use a pseudo-random number generator to identify number between 1 and 4 and then round it off to the closest two decimal places
2. Generate all the numbers between 1.00 and 4.00 and use a random number to select from this array

Is each number in the search space from 1.00 to 4.00 equally likely for both use cases ?

[Edge conditions like rounding off (0.5 above) can be safely omitted .]

Answer (score 1):

No, in the second case, all numbers are equally likely. But, in the first case, (call your unrounded random number as $X$), you get $1.00$ only when $X < 1.005$, (similar situation for $4.00$), which has probability $\frac{0.005}{3}$. However, in order to get, let's say, $1.01$, your random number needs to fit in the range: $1.005 < X < 1.015$, which has twice the probability.